# Flutter Staggered Grid View Tile not defined

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement the Quilted Grid View from this Flutter package but it appears it cannot find the Tile class. This is the code I am looking at below with the documentation link.

```
GridView.custom(
  gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
    crossAxisCount: 4,
    mainAxisSpacing: 4,
    crossAxisSpacing: 4,
    repeatPattern: QuiltedGridRepeatPattern.inverted,
    pattern: [
      QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 2),
    ],
  ),
  childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (context, index) => Tile(index: index),
  ),
)
```

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Here is a Flutlab (need an account to view) of what I am trying to do: https://flutlab.io/ide/3451b0b7-753c-44bb-89f8-6b9a8290f7fe

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Tile` class is provided by google_maps_flutter and this is not a widget.

height and width are double and `data` is `Uint8List?`

```dart
const Tile(this.width, this.height, this.data);
```

You need to return a widget form `SliverChildBuilderDelegate`. You can use `GridTile()`

```dart
childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
  (context, index) => GridTile(child: child)),
),
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for the GridTile worked perfect for what I was trying to do. The Tile() is very confusing and seems to be misleading in what it does here. I still cannot seem to find information about the Tile() class even after looking under foundation. Do you have a resource so I can learn more?

Comment: I've missed something Tile class  comes from [google_maps_flutter](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/lib/src/types/tile.dart) , You can find more about [GridTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/GridTile-class.html)